Does the function $z^5 \sin \left( \frac{1}{z^2}\right)$ have a primitive in an annulus?

Does the function $f(z)=z^5 \sin \left( \frac{1}{z^2}\right)$ have a primitive in $\{ z\in \mathbb{C} | 1<|z|<2 \}$?

My thought is that to prove a function has a primitive, I want to prove the function is holomorphic in a simply-connected domain. Now, this function is of course holomorphic in all the given domain, but the problem is that it is not simply-connected, which means an alternative approach is required.
Thinking about the Laurent series for this case didn't help me much either:
$z^5 \sin \left( \frac{1}{z^2}\right) = z^5\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n z^{-4n-2}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n z^{-4n+3}}{(2n+1)!}$.
Will be happy to hear your thoughts on this one.
Thank you

do you mean by integrating term-by-term? Does it give me a primitive in terms of elementary functions? I wasn't sure how to recognize it
Thanks

@RT1 This is not a power series though, it's a Laurent series. If the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ (the residue) was $0$ then you could take the antiderivative term by term. But here looks like it isn't the case.

@Dr.John It would be the case if you didn't have a $z^{-1}$ term in the series.

Thank you all for your remarks. Do you have any idea about how to approach this question?

@Dr.John Looks like it's just not true. If $g(z)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ was a primitive then we would get $f$ by differentiating the series term by term, which would show its residue is equal to $0$.

why do you think the result is true?

Thank you all for your comments. If the claim is not true, then what is an appropriate way to explain it doesn't have a primitive? The function is holomorphic in this ring, so I am not sure how to explain this. Thanks

Btw just passing through, OP may want to edit their use of "ring" to "annulus" as this is the common terminology.

@Dr.John the issue is the same as when you try to find a primitive of $\frac{1}{z}$ on say $\mathbb C^*$. this is not possible, because if $f$ were such a holomorphic function (ie $f'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$) then we would have $\int_{S^1} f'(z) dz=f(1)-f(1)=0$, which is not possible since $\int_{S^1} \frac{1}{z} dz=2i\pi$ by Cauchy's formula.

The function is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus {0}.$ We can represent it as $z^5\sin(z^{-2})=g(z)-{1\over 3}z^{-1},$ where $g(z)=z^5\sin(z^{-2})+{1\over 3}z^{-1}.$ The function $g$ admits an antiderivative while $z^{-1} $ does not.

@Dr.John $f$ has a primitive if and only if $\int_\gamma f~\mathrm{d}z = 0$ for every path $\gamma$ that is contained in the domain of $f$. It is equivalent that $\mathrm{Res}_0(f)= 0$. So just compute the Laurent Series and check the residue.
